# Remove bottom bar from Excel Embed iFrame

Tags: html, css, excel, wordpress, iframe

I want to embed an Excel sheet with formulas and some calculation to a Wordpress site. I managed to setup and display the sheet and able to interact with it live on my site. The guide I used to embed is as follows:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-it-Embed-an-Excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-OneDrive-804e1845-5662-487e-9b38-f96307144081?CorrelationId=2f1048d2-df73-470f-b3a5-c65576288a04&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102029502

Now, I just need one help that is to remove the bottom black bar that comes preloaded with the Microsoft embed code. Please refer below, where I have highlighted in red. The reason for me to remove that is to prevent users from downloading the Excel from my site.

[image: The bottom black bar]

Answer (score 2):

I know is a really old question, but I hope this helps someone in the future:
As you may realized when "inspecting" the element in the browser it happens that the excel embed has another iframe inside! This iframe has an ID called *"WebApplicationFrame"*, and bottom bar is inside this second iframe.
I tried to add a **"display: none"** to the bar with JS to hide it, but for some reason it doesn't work. So the way I achieved this was doing bigger the height of "WebApplicationFrame":

```
<iframe id="excel-iframe" scrolling="no" src="YOUR_EXCEL_EMBED_URL" width="600" height="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#excel-iframe").load(function() {
         $(this).contents().find("#WebApplicationFrame").css("height", "550px");
      });
   });
</script>
```

Notice in my code that the iframe where you are embedding the excel has a **height of 500 (pixels)** and in the Javascript code I'm giving the iframe within a **height of 550px**. This way the bottom bar of the internal iframe is out of viewport.

---

Now, maybe you don't care about hiding the bottom bar and you may only want to disable the "download" button. If you watch your embed URL there's a part in it which says:

```
&wdDownloadButton=True
```

you just need to change True for False and the download button will be disabled:

```
&wdDownloadButton=False
```